# How to export data with latin1 character set and maintains this character set

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a MySQL database in which the data are stored with a latin1 character encoding.

I need to porting these data in a new environment within a mysql database but with full support to utf8 encoding.

I have read many post and finally for resolve this problem I have opted to export data with mysqldump without any special parameter as the option --default-character-set. This seems to work correctly, but I have many doubts about it.

Is this the correct way to resolve this problem?
If not, how I can export and import these data and maintains their the original encoding?

Some technical information. I need to perform this migration through two server linux Ubuntu on which mysql is at the version 5.6.33.

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks again, Lorenzo.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *export* your Latin-1 data and then *import* it into a new database transcoded to UTF-8? Or do you want to import it into a database for which the default setting is UTF-8, but you want your data to still be coded in Latin1 after you import it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi O. Jones. Yes, I need to import data into a database in which the default setting is UTF-8, but I want my data to still be coded in Latin1 after my import. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care what the stored charset is?  My point is, you can hide this detail.  Anyway, I will tell you how to store it that way if you must.

When exporting, specify that the file be written either latin1 or utf8 or utf8mb4.

When importing, first declare that the import file is in *that* encoding.

Then declare the column(s) and table(s) to be latin1 or utf8 or utf8mb4.  The load will trancode if necessary.

All latin1 characters have a corresponding utf8/utf8mb4/UTF-8 encoding so what it will not stumble *in your scenario*.

You *should* build all new tables with utf8mb4.  The server is *defaulting* to utf8; you *can* override it on your column/table declarations.

It is OK to have a column declared latin1 but connect with utf8mb4.  Again, the transcoding will be transparent and loss-less (or reading).